# Using React, how do I make the value of my variable dynamic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to be able to do this:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.props.user.cart.length; i++) {
  return (
    <div>
      {"products.desserts." + this.props.user.cart[i] + ".name"}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And have JSX read it as a call to my json. Instead, it just spits out a string.

The string it gives is products.desserts.cakes.cake1.name, which is correct if it would actually access the name in my json file.

I've seen some stuff about dynamic variable names and I'm not completely sure if that's the right direction to go since I keep getting errors when attempting it.
(Very new to React by the way)

Comment: What is the string that is being output? It should output a string, just probably not the one you want.

Comment: It should return the name of the product. So in this case, this.props.user.cart[0] is equal to cakes.cake1, which with everything else would return "Chocolate Cake"

Comment: read that wrong, it is currently outputting "products.desserts.cakes.cake1.name"

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access an object key with strings instead of a dot `.` .

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.props.auth.cart.length; i++) {
  return (
    <div>
      {products.desserts[this.props.user.cart[i].name]}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Edit**
As a followup to your comment:

> I want it to be accessing "`products.desserts.cakes.cake1.name`"

This `cakes.cake1` is not a valid key for an object, hence you would need to split the `.` of the value in your array and use double brackets.
So in your case:

```
{
  const splitedKeys = this.props.user.cart[i].split(".");
  const key1 = splitedKeys[0];
  const key2 = splitedKeys[1];
  products.desserts[key1][key2].name
}
```

A simple example:

```js
const products = {
  desserts: {
    cakes: {
      cake1: {
        name: 'cake 1'
      },
      cake2: {
        name: 'cake 2'
      }
    }
  }
}

const cart = ['cakes.cake1', 'cakes.cake2'];

cart.forEach((val) => {
  const splitedKeys = val.split('.'); // split the values by the "."
  const key1 = splitedKeys[0] // left side of the "."
  const key2 = splitedKeys[1] // right side of the "."
  console.log(products.desserts[key1][key2].name)
});
```

Comment: This gives me the error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".

Comment: i'm not sure if `products.desserts` is an array or an object and what kind of structure you got there. i'm guessing it's either `products.desserts[this.props.user.cart[i].name]` or `products.desserts[this.props.user.cart[i]].name`. again depends on your data structure

Comment: I have a json file I''m using. So essentially I want it to be accessing "products.desserts.cakes.cake1.name", this.props.user.cart[0] having the value "cakes.cake1"

Comment: well `cakes.cake1` is not a valid key of an object. you should split the value with the dot (`.`) and try accessing it with double crackets. i will update my answer

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I guess it was a poor choice for me to push cakes.cake to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the string quotes and wrap your JSX in `{}`:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.props.auth.cart.length; i++) {
  const item = products.desserts[this.props.user.cart[i]];
  return (
    <div>
      {item ? item.name : 'N/A'}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @Sag1v Haha okay I was like what's going on??

Comment: Does not work sadly :/ this tells me it cannot read property name of undefined

Comment: @Sophie Updated answer. Although, that most likely means there is something wrong with your data or `this.props.user.cart` does not contain the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to output a string `products.desserts.someValue.name`, then this will work:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.props.auth.cart.length; i++) {
  return (
    <div>
      products.desserts.{this.props.user.cart[i]}.name
    </div>
  );
}
```

What you have would work as well, but this is a little cleaner.

If you want to output the variable `products.desserts.someValue.name`, then you can do something like:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.props.auth.cart.length; i++) {
  return (
    <div>
      {products.desserts[this.props.user.cart[i]].name}    
    </div>
  );
}
```

Basically, only treat the part that is actually dynamic as dynamic, and treat the rest like a normal variable.

Answer (score 0):

Some gotchas:

1. A component must return a react element(basically a div , span etc in JSX) or null. Make sure you are returning one and only one react element and not multiple. If there are more, wrap them in one and return the wrapper.
2. If the code you have given is returned from a component, you may do as following:

   ```
   const items= this.props.auth.cart.map((item, index) => {
              let val = products.desserts[this.props.user.cart[index]];
              return (
                   <div>
                        {val && val.name}
                  </div>
              );
   });
   ```

Then just return items wrapped in a div.